# Logarithmic derivative of Polygamma functions

Tags: derivatives, special-functions, gamma-function

While studying Gamma function and related functions I noticed that its logarithmic derivative (the so-called Digamma function) is studied more than its "normal" derivative but on the other hand I can't find anything on the logarithmic derivative of the Digamma function but only its usual derivatives (the so-called Polygamma functions).

So my question is: have already been studied the logarithmic derivatives of the Polygamma functions and they are not interesting (and maybe why they are not?) or none simply ever cared about ?

Comment: Well, your logarithmic derivative is merely $\frac{\psi^{(k+1)}(x)}{\psi^{(k)}(x)}$; as to why one would be interested in ratios of (shifted, generalized) harmonic numbers, I've no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\Gamma$ function is defined as the analytic continuation (through $\Gamma(z+1)=z\,\Gamma(z)$) of
$$ \Gamma(\alpha)=\int_{0}^{+\infty} t^{\alpha-1}e^{-t}\,dt,\qquad\text{Re}(\alpha)>0 $$
so it is a meromorphic function over $\mathbb{C}$ with simple poles at $z=0,-1,-2,\ldots$.

By the Mittag-Leffler theorem or through other ways (for instance, the dominated convergence theorem that leads to the Euler product) we have that $\Gamma(z+1)$ can be represented by an infinite product:
$$ \Gamma(z+1) = e^{-\gamma z}\prod_{n\geq 1}\left(1+\frac{z}{n}\right)^{-1}e^{\frac{z}{n}}\tag{1}$$
that is the Weierstrass product. Hence $\log\Gamma $ can be represented by a series, as well as:
$$ \psi(z+1) = \frac{d}{dz}\log\Gamma(z+1) = -\gamma+\sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+z}\right).\tag{2}$$
We also have an integral representation:
$$ \psi(z+1)=-\gamma+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-t^z}{1-t}\,dt,\qquad \text{Re}(z)>-1\tag{3}$$
but the functional equation $\psi(z+1)=\frac{1}{z}+\psi(z)$ does not lead to a practical representation of the digamma function as a product. That is the reason for which we never met the logarithmic derivative of the digamma function: despite it just is $\frac{\psi'}{\psi}$, $\frac{\psi'}{\psi}$ does not satisfy a nice functional equation.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is founded upon wrong assumptions. The reason for studying the derivative of the natural logarithm of the $\Gamma$ function is because factorials show an [explosive growth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation), which far outweighs even that of the exponential function itself, so, in an era before the advent of modern computers, the natural logarithm of the $\Gamma$ function was studied as [a function in its own right](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogGammaFunction.html), hence the historic definition of the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function). But since $\psi(n+1)=H_n-\gamma$, “taming” such a incredibly-slow-increasing function by taking its logarithm makes little or no sense.